# Exteral HDD problems

Tags: hard-drive

I currently have some annoying problem with external HDD. I'm using some old (7yrs) WD  salvaged from laptop in portable enclosure. I have external 4A PSU wich power drive and backfeed rpi. Disk is formatted in NTFS, I added some lines fstab to auto mount it. I distabled power saving options. Everything is good but after few days of usage I'm unable to acces files on it (mainly music on MPD service). Dmesg show multiple : Buffer I/O error on device sdaX, logical block X and Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block X, async page read X. 
It is possible that drive itself is failing form old age ?

[image]

I don't have full logs at this moment but It show one I/O error msg, they just multiply when I'm trying to acces files.

Comment: Can you please post a full log? It depends on the precise message

Answer (score 1):

If it was working to start with and then began to fail, I suspect drive age issues.  Install smartmontools (`sudo apt-get install smartmontools`) and run a short test (`sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda`).  Wait about five minutes then get the results (`sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`).  You'll see a bunch of info, most of which you can ignore, but if you see any "FAIL" or such, then you can know the drive is faulty.  A long test (`sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda`) will take much longer but will expose more potential issues.

If you don't see any problems there, check the filesystem; perhaps it was not unmounted cleanly at some point.  You'll need to connect the drive to a Windows system to properly check an NTFS filesystem.